# Flutter Table Calendar (v.3.0.2) : Show all data from REST API based on date

Tags: flutter, dart, rest

I'm trying to load all data objects fetched from REST API into TableCalendar and show their values under the calendar based on the currently picked date

**Response** looks like this:

```
 [{
   "id" : "abc321",
   "name" : "header1",
   "description" : "desc1",
   "date" : {
    "day" : 10,
    "month" : 10,
    "year" : 2020
  },
 }, 
 {
   "id" : "321abc",
   "name" : "header2",
   "description" : "desc2",
   "date" : {
   "day" : 5,
   "month" : 5,
   "year" : 2020
  },
 }]
```

**FetchData** Future looks like this:

```
Future<List<ObjectName>>? getData() async {
    const String url = 'urlOfAPI';

    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      return parsed.map<ObjectName>((json) => ObjectName.fromJson(json)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
    }
  }
```

**TableCalendar** initial code:

```
CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.twoWeeks;
DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
DateTime? _selectedDay = DateTime.now();

return TableCalendar(
  firstDay: DateTime.now(),
  lastDay: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 10),
  focusedDay: _focusedDay,
  calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
  selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
    return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
  },
  onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
    if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      });
    }
  },
  onFormatChanged: (format) {
    if (_calendarFormat != format) {
      setState(() {
        _calendarFormat = format;
      });
    }
  },
  onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
    _focusedDay = focusedDay;
  },
);
```

**e.g.**
I'd like to show all objects inside the calendar and show only "*object1*" or "object2" values under the calendar when picked date is "*10/10/2020*" or "*5/5/20*" respectively.